# Problems using OVER ( PARTITION BY ... )) with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Here's my problem : everything in my code seems to be fine, though it doesn,t work so there's definitly something I'm not seeing. I need to get the max date for any of the tx, but the txs can have many states and different time, and they can go back and forth on every states. Yet, I need the date of the lates for each of them.

Without using OVER (PARTITION BY ...), I get those kind of results :

```
   |txCode|stateDateTime
1  | tx1  | 2018-06-11 10:50:25
2  | tx1  | 2018-06-11 10:51:25
3  | tx1  | 2018-06-11 12:52:25
4  | tx2  | 2018-06-11 08:10:20
5  | tx2  | 2018-06-11 10:08:37
6  | tx2  | 2018-06-11 11:53:21
```

Basically, I would like to have something like this :

```
1  | tx1  | 2018-06-11 12:52:25
2  | tx2  | 2018-06-11 11:53:21
```

```
SELECT
    tx.code AS txCode,
    MAX(txState.`datetime`) OVER ( 
        PARTITION BY tx.code
    ) AS stateDateTime
FROM
    tx AS tx
    JOIN tx_state AS txState ON txState.tx_id = tx.id
```

When I run this, I get an SQL synthax error :

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 
        PARTITION BY tx.code
    )) AS stateDateTime,
```

So, basically, I don't see my mistake there. Is there something I don,t see? Or is there a bigger mistake here?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: MySQL before version 8.X doesn't support window functions.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm using an older version. I'll have to figure out another way to do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want aggregation:

```
SELECT tx.code AS txCode,
       MAX(s.`datetime`) as stateDateTime
FROM tx JOIN
    tx_state s
    ON s.tx_id = tx.id
GROUP BY tx.code;
```

Comment: Using MAX on the date and then grouping by tx.code makes it so I only get one row with the max txStateDate of all of the txState. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorpAgent . . . That is **exactly** what your desired results look like.

Comment: Using MAX, it shrinks EVERYTHING down to a single row. I need one row for every tx.code. This is why I want to use PARTITION BY. But turns out my version of MySQL doesn't support window functions (I'm using 5.7.17, it's only supported with 8.x and over). Thanks anyways! Appreciated!

Comment: @UmbrellaCorpAgent, `MAX()` will return one row if you don't also use `GROUP BY`... In Gordon's query, he's grouping by `tx.code`, therefore it will return two rows based on your supplied data in the question.